# Mysql Select query error in live server : Errcode: 28 - No space left on device

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Mysql Select query error in live server

> Errcode: 28 - No space left on device

We have more space but, still show this error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::query(): (HY000/3): Error writing file
>   '/tmp/MY0htELg' (Errcode: 28 - No space left on device)
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Comment: Show the output from console # df -uh

Comment: May be your partition where  mysql  resides is full

Comment: Dear @M Khalid Junaid.
Where to find partition of mysql in cpanel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, the partition ***/tmp*** is I believe is completely filled 
you can check this using

```
df -kh
```

this should tell you various partitions and their use percentage. something like this as output

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  9.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda5       123G   19G   98G  17% /
```

you need to look for mount point with very high Use% . and get rid of some files or add more disk

**please note**: that you may have disk space overall but, MySQL is interested in this specific mount point

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the partition /tmp is I believe is completely filled you can check this using

df -kh
this should tell you various partitions and their use percentage. something like this as output